# When is a matrix-valued function the Hessian of some function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

What are necessary and sufficient conditions for a matrix valued function $H: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d\times{}d}$ to be the Hessian of a convex scalar function $F:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $H(x) = \nabla^2 F(x)$.

I have heard informally that the following are necessary and sufficient:
1) $H(x)$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite
2) $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} H_{ij}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} H_{ik}(x)$ for all $i,j,k$
however, I have not been able to find any rigorous statement.

Answer (score 1):

First, for each $1 \le i \le d$, let $$V_i = (H_{i1}, \dots, H_{id}),$$ and verify that it is a conservative vector field. Recall that a conservative vector field on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is gradient and therefore, there are scalar functions $G_i$ such that $$\nabla G_i = V_i.$$ Now verify that the vector field $G = (G_1, \dots,G_d)$ is a conservative and therefore a gradient vector field. It follows that there exists a scalar function $H$ such that $$\nabla G = F.$$ Verify that this implies that $H$ is the Hessian of $F$.

A necessary and sufficient condition for $F$ to be convex is that its Hessian be positive semidefinite. It's a good exercise to try to prove this yourself.