# When is a matrix-valued function the Hessian of some (not nec. convex) function?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

What are necessary and sufficient conditions for a matrix-valued function $H: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d\times{}d}$ to be the Hessian of a scalar function $F:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $H(x) = \nabla^2 F(x)$.

Is equality of mixed partials enough?

Another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3544229/when-is-a-matrix-valued-function-the-hessian-of-some-function) asks this but requires $F$ to be convex.